# Ansible - using with_items and when conditional to

Tags: ansible

I have a bunch of servers that have four physical drives on them (/dev/sda, sdb, sdc, and sdd). sda has the OS installed on it.

I need to format each drive except sda. I need to check if each drive has data on it.  If it does, then I shouldn't format it.

```
# This will get all physical disks (sda, sdb, sdc, etc) and assign them to disk_var
- name: Get disks
  set_fact: disk_var="{{hostvars[inventory_hostname]["ansible_devices"].keys()|list}}"

- name: Check if the disk is partitioned and also ignore sda
  stat: path=/dev/{{item}}1
  with_items: disk_var
  when: item != 'sda'
  register: base_secondary_partition_{{item}}

- name: Create GPT partition table
  command: /sbin/parted -s /dev/{{item}} mklabel gpt
  with_items: disk_var
  when: item != 'sda' and base_secondary_partition_{{item}}.stat.exists == false
```

There's clearly more steps involved into formatting these drives but it fails at the last task when creating the GPT partition table.

Here's what it looks like when it runs.  You'll see that it fails at the last task:

```
TASK: [role | Get disks] ******************************************************
ok: [server1.com]

TASK: [role | Check if the disk is partitioned] *******************************
skipping: [server1.com] => (item=sda)
ok: [server1.com] => (item=sdd)
ok: [server1.com] => (item=sdb)
ok: [server1.com] => (item=sdc)

TASK: [role | Create GPT partition table] *************************************
fatal: [server1.com] => error while evaluating conditional: base_secondary_partition_sdd.stat.exists == false

FATAL: all hosts have already failed -- aborting
```

Any idea how I can check the conditional `base_secondary_partition_{{item}}.stat.exists`? I need to make sure that if there's data on the drive, it will not format it.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

You do not need to register your result with the `item` salt. When you register the result of a loop (e.g. `with_items`) the registered value will contain a key `results` which holds a list of all results of the loop. (See [docs](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_loops.html#registering-variables-with-a-loop))

Instead of looping over your original device list, you can loop over the registered results of the first task then:

```
- name: Check if the disk is partitioned and also ignore sda
  stat: path=/dev/{{item}}1
  with_items: disk_var
  when: item != 'sda'
  register: device_stat

- name: Create GPT partition table
  command: /sbin/parted -s /dev/{{ item.item }} mklabel gpt
  with_items: "{{ device_stat.results }}"
  when:
    - item is not skipped 
    - item.stat.exists == false
```

The condition `not item | skipped` takes care of that elements which have been filtered in the original loop (sda) will not be processed.

While that might be a solution to your problem, your question is very interesting. There seems to be no `eval` feature in Jinja2. While you can concatenate strings you can not use that string as a variable name to get to its value...

Comment: You should use `{{item.item}}` for the second task.

Comment: Excellent! This should be in ansible examples.

Comment: `not item | skipped` gives errors in more recent versions of ansible.  I don't know if you can run functions like not on a filtered expression and skipped is only defined if if it actually skipped.  Anyways I ended up doing `item.skipped is not defined or item.skipped == false`

Comment: In Ansible >= v2.2 you need to use `with_items: "{{ device_stat.results }}"` for this to to work.

Comment: ```not item | skipped``` gives this warning "[DEPRECATION WARNING]: Using tests as filters is deprecated. Instead of using `result|skipped` use `result is skipped`. This feature will be removed in version 2.9. Deprecation warnings can be disabled by setting deprecation_warnings=False in ansible.cfg." This should be the far more readable ```item is not skipped```

Answer (score 10):

Your tasks can be as simple as this...

```
- stat:
    path: /dev/{{item}}1
  with_items: ansible_devices.keys()
  when: item != 'sda'
  register: stats
- command: /sbin/parted -s /dev/{{item.item}} mklabel gpt
  with_items: stats.results
  when: item.stat | default(false) and item.stat.exists
```