# By using ansible-facts, how do I identify all disks that are NOT already mounted and then mount?

Tags: ansible, ansible-facts

I have a number of disks, with 1 partition on them, preformatted with ext4. AND some times new disks that are blank. I need to be able to stick them in any of our ubuntu servers, run an ansible playbook that:
identifys (new) disks
ensures that it is not already mounted
ensures that we do not touch the rootdisk
if new, creates partition and ext4 filesystem.
creates mountpoints for the new disks like "/mnt/{newdiskserial}
stores this in a variable so I can extend the playbook functionality
mounts the new disk(s)

I have been looking at this old answer: [Ansible - using with_items and when conditional to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32214529/ansible-using-with-items-and-when-conditional-to)
I think it might be usable, or adaptable. But my ansible woodoo is not strong enough. I need a highlevel hand.

No functioning code

End result should be.
Put in a few new disks OR used ones with filesystem. Run playbook and see that they are mounted in /mnt/serialnumber

Answer (score 5):

Ansible is designed to be idempotent, so taking an action such as formatting or mounting a partition should not have any impact if it's already partitioned and/or formatted with the filesystem you are expecting.

Your question sounds like you are looking to Ansible to behave more like a generic language; if it helps, think of Ansible as a tool/language that **makes** things look a certain way regardless.  And what parts of the system are correct already (e.g. partition 1 exists, or formatted as "ext4"), then Ansible says "Good, that's correct, let's move on to the next step."

Imagine Ansible as a (very) junior system administrator that you have to explain things to in a check-list format.  Your situation would then be something like this - your question said "No functioning code" so I'll keep this high-level:

1. Make a list of all possible disks and call that "my_disk_list".

```
  my_disk_list:
  - "sdb"
  - "sdc"
  - "sdd"
```

1. Make sure each disk has a partition

   - Hint: `with_items: my_disk_list`
2. Make sure each partition #1 is formatted `ext4`

   - Hint: Another `with_items` and the `filesystem` module with `force: no`.
3. Make sure each mount point is created

   - Hint: Yet another `with_items`
4. Mount them at "/mount/my_disk_name"

   - Hint: You guessed it, yet another `with_items`

If you use the `register` command in each section, you can then keep track of which actions were changed or left alone at each step.

If you need to mount using the disks serial number, you will have to loop over the Ansible "setup:" module facts for each disk and use that to setup the mount point.

Comment: Thank you, that was actually a very useful answer. I will try to build it that way. I will report the progress/share the resulting code here.

Comment: Can you up-vote the comment and accept it as your answer, please? :)