# Loop with conditional statement

Tags: ansible

Is it possible to have loop with conditional statement in Ansible? What I want is to find whether a path exists for a specific file. If it exists, to perform a loop, and only for that specific file to see conditional statement. Code sample below

```yaml
  - name: File exist
    stat:
      path: <path to the file or directory you want to check>
    register: register_name

- name: Copy file
  copy:
    src: '{{ item }}'
    dest: '<destination path>'
  with_fileglob:
    - ../spring.jar
    - <perform if statement. if register_name.stat.exists, ../info.txt, else dont copy this info.txt >


# ... few other task with loop instead of with_fileglob
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can and the pseudo code you are providing is close to a solution that would work.

There is an [*inline if expression*](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/templates/#if-expression) that can make you act on the items of the list.
From there on, you could make an empty string if the file your where expecting does not exist — *because, sadly, you cannot [`omit`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#making-variables-optional) an element of a list*.

Because a `copy` with an empty element will make it fail, you now have two options, either filter the list to remove empty elements or make a condition with a `when` to skip them.

Here would be the solution filtering empty elements, with the [`select`](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/templates/#jinja-filters.select) filter:

```yaml
- copy:
    src: "{{ item }}"
    dest: /tmp
  loop: "{{ _loop | select }}"
  vars:
    _loop:
      - ../spring.jar
      - "{{ '../info.txt' if register_name.stat.exists else '' }}"
```

And here is the solution using a condition:

```yaml
- copy:
    src: "{{ item }}"
    dest: /tmp
  loop:
    - ../spring.jar
    - "{{ '../info.txt' if register_name.stat.exists else '' }}"
  when: "item != ''"
```

Answer (score 3):

Regarding

> *Is it possible to have loop with conditional statement in Ansible?*

sure, according [Loops](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#iterating-over-a-list-of-hashes)

> *When combining [conditionals](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_conditionals.html#playbooks-conditionals) with a loop, the `when:` statement is processed separately for each item. See [Basic conditionals with when](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_conditionals.html#the-when-statement) for examples.*

**Further Q&A**

- [Ansible - Using `with_items` and `when` conditional](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32218765/6771046)